# scraping inside of iframe with Beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm working on scraping using Beautifulsoup.

But as the target which is price is in `iframe`, so cannot get the target.
The target is as below.

```
<span class="last">1,025.5</span>
```

Would you please advise how I can get the target.
my coding is as below.

```
stock = ""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.xxxxxx.com/jp/ir/'
html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")
span = soup.find_all("span")

for tag in span:
try:
    string_ = tag.get("class").pop(0)

    if string_ in "last":
        stock = tag.string
        break
except:
    nodata = "データが見つかりません"
    print (nodata)
    break

print(stock)
```

Comment: I believe you need to load the iframe's src in a new request since it's loaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soup is a plain HTML parser. It isn't a wrapper around a browser.

If you want content that isn't part of the document you requested (e.g. because it is generated by JavaScript or in a different document that is loaded in an iframe), it won't fetch it for you automatically.

To get the data from the iframe, you'll need to read the `src` attribute from the document you have, then make a new HTTP request to the URL that resolves to, then parse that document.

Comment: This is not at all a helpful answer. A helpful answer would contain code and an explanation of how it works.

Comment: All the code needed to solve this is *already in the question*. Rewriting it would be less clear then the simple one sentence solution that explains to how apply techniques the OP clearly already grasps.